# meaning of "drive off with sb"

Tags: meaning

[A post](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing) says

> He saw her **drive off with** a young man in the passenger seat.

which uses the pattern "drive off with sb". I [googled it](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&sxsrf=ALeKk03QcO-c3tsIE37XnFrYGAU2nsmnRQ%3A1587106676521&ei=dFOZXpW1H8COr7wPrc6aiAc&q=meaning%20of%20%22drive%20off%20with%20sb%22&oq=meaning%20of%20%22drive%20off%20with%20sb%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFAAWABgnCBoAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiVv7KN8e7oAhVAx4sBHS2nBnEQ4dUDCAw) and the hits point to "drive off", which means

> If you drive someone or something off, you **force** them to go away and to stop attacking you or threatening you.

I suspect whether it is the meaning in the first quotation.

Consider this simplified version

> Alice **drive off with** Michael.

Does that mean "Alice force Michael to go away" or something else?

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

---

["sb"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sb) refers to "somebody" or "someone"

Comment: *Drive someone off* is transitive usage, while *drive off with someone* isn't, so it can't possibly be that. You googled, sure, but you stopped at the first *impossible* result. Please, next time try clicking on the second Google result. (And the third, and so on, if the previous one didn't answer your question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two meanings. Here, "drive off" (a phrasal verb) means

> [to leave in a car](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drive-off) (Cambridge)
>   - *I got in the car and drove off*.

Also, see ["drive off"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/drive-off) in Macmillan:

> If a vehicle or driver drives off, the vehicle starts moving and leaves.
>   - *They stood and waved as we drove off*.

Michael Harvey pointed out in a comment that "drive off" can also be used for a passenger. Note the use of "we" in the second example.

Comment: Note that we can say someone 'drove off' in a car, even if that person was a passenger in the car, and not actually the driver.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Noted, thanks!